# Kendo Treeview checkbox check by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, treeview

I'm trying to bind a Kendo Treeview with Checkboxes to a datasource, and then check specific checkboxes by the node id..
Here is what I have so far, I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
    function bindCheckboxToId(treeView, id) {


            var el = treeView.findByUid(id);
            var cb = el.find(".k-checkbox input");
            if (cb) {
                $(cb.selector).prop('checked', true);
            }

      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the UID already, would it work for you to get at this via the `dataSource`.  That way the UI and backing source stay in sync?

```
function bindCheckboxToId2(treeView, id){
  var data = treeView.dataSource.getByUid(id);
    if (data) {
      data.set("checked", true);
    }
}
```

Which can then be called with 
`bindCheckboxToId2($("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView"),  "0c9802d5-770d-41ba-9aec-8233c708a5ce")`

Comment: Thank you!!, i didn't realize you could check the box straight from the dataSource